# Thunderbird Conversations disables keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I noticed that almost all my keyboard shortcuts are disabled when I view a message in a new window with Conversation view.  This includes things like next message, previous message, find, reply to all.

Note, that these shortcuts all work when I'm in my inbox looking at a list of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of Conversations.

Yes, unfortunately, implementing the navigation in a separate tab requires a fair bit of work. It's not unfeasible, but that would probably require me to spend an entire week working full-time on this, and I don't have that time right now :) (I'm doing Conversations on my free time).

There's an old issue filed about this at https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/issues/333 ; if you're interested in helping out, I'd be more than happy to provide guidance and pointers as to how one could implement this :).

Comment: That's too bad to hear but thanks for responding nonetheless.  I was beginning to think I was going crazy :)